# Why I get error when I change data in ajax call

Tags: ajax, web-services

I have this ajax call :

```
   function ExecuteQuery(wkt) {
      var data = "wkt=" + wkt;
      $.ajax({
         url: "..some Service",
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         success: function () {
         },
         error: function () {
         }
         });
    }
```

Here is service signature:

```
 public void ExecuteQuery(string wkt){}
```

when I change it to this(make data:wkt)I get error:

```
   function ExecuteQuery(wkt) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "..some Service",
        type: "POST",
        data: wkt,//here!!
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

I get error  500 (Internal Server Error).

Any Idea why I get error.

Comment: What is the value of `wkt` in the second block of code when you get an error?

Comment: You need to specify the key of the value, something like `'wkt=value'` or object like `{wkt: 'value'}`